# Permission Settings Ignored when creating file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Application Owned Accounts to create a file. However, I would like the ownership of the file to be transfered to other users. The code below works but permission settings are ignored, so I am not the owner of the file. File ownership stays with the Application Owned Account, so files cannot be deleted permanently.

```
public File uploadEmptyFile(String title, String subFolderName, String mimetype) throws GDriveAccessException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(title);
    fileMetadata.setMimeType(mimetype);
    Permission newPermission = new Permission();

    newPermission.setValue("xxx@xyz.com");
    newPermission.setType("user");
    newPermission.setRole("owner");

    fileMetadata.setUserPermission(newPermission);
    if (subFolderName==null){
        fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(FOLDER_ID)));
    }else{
        fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(new  ParentReference().setId(getFileIdByFolderNName(null,subFolderName))));
    }


    File faux=null;
    try {
        faux= getDrive().files().insert(fileMetadata).execute();
        return faux;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    throw new GDriveAccessException(e1);
    }

  }
```

Any help in identifying why the permission settings are being ignored would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [permissions.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) as outlined in the [sharing and permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing) documentation.

Comment: I am getting An error occurred: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
} could it be that the ownership is being transferred out of the domain? If so, there is no solution because the App Specific account is always @developer.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, I found that the issue was that ownership cannot be changed on regular google apps accounts. You need to have a premium license to transfer file ownership.

Second, I found that what I actually neeeded was impersonation:

```
public static Drive getDrive() throws GDriveAccessException {
    if(drive == null) {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new UrlFetchTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential;
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                  .setTransport(httpTransport)
                  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                  .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(getPrivateKey())
                  .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
                  .setServiceAccountUser("xxx@xyz.com")// Use this property for impersonation
                  .build();
      Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
          .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
      drive=service;
      return service;
    }
    return drive;
}
```

It would be nice to have better documentation about this feature, Google.